# Routes in route6-eth0 don't apply

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, centos8, iproute2, static-routes

I made a file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route6-eth0 with the following contents:

```
default dev eth0 src ****:****::**** metric 50 pref medium
```

However, it doesn't show up when I execute ip -6 route:

```
# ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
****:****:****:****::/64 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
****:****::**** dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
default via ****::****:****:****:**** dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

I did the same for IPv4, and there it works fine, /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 contents:

```
default dev eth0 src ***.***.***.*** metric 50
```

ip route:

```
# ip route
default dev eth0 proto static scope link src ***.***.***.*** metric 50
default via ***.***.***.*** dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
***.***.***.*** via ***.***.***.*** dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
***.***.***.***/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src ***.***.***.*** metric 100
```

My goal with this config is to change the default source address, which works for IPv4. I think the route6 is not working because of router advertisements, but that's just a guess. Maybe the RA overrides the routes.

Comment: you've tried to not to disclose your ip addresses, but resulting mess is ***, and no one can read it.